# Suppose $G$ denotes the multiplicative group $(-1,1)$ and $S=(z\in C:|z|=1)$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ denotes the multiplicative group {$-1,1$} and $S=${$z\in \mathbb C:|z|=1$}. Let $G$ act on $S$ by complex multiplication.Then the cardinality of the orbit of $i$ is

$a)1$

$b)2$

$c)5 $

$d)\infty$

Comment: MSE shouldn't be used as alternative to reading through course material. I'm sure orbit is one of the first things defined after introducing notion of group action.

Answer (score 1):

It's two. The orbit of $i$ is the set $G{i}=\{x\in S : x=g\cdot i$, with $ g\in \{-1,1\}\}$. Hence $G{i}=\{i,-i\}$.

Comment: what is orbit?i donot have any knowledge about it..plz expain it

Comment: Why are you asking this question if you don't know what an orbit is?

Comment: If you have a group G acting on a set X . The orbit of an element $x\in X$ is the set $Gx=\{y\in X  : y=g\cdot x, g\in G\}$

Comment: actual i found this problem from question paper..

Comment: Please first look up, what a group operation and an orbit is. Then your question should answer itself in a few seconds!